# Notepad++ Bookmarking Sections

Tags: xml, notepad++, bookmarks

I'm trying to find a means to bookmark entire sections of XML code in Notepad++ based on part of the block matching a search criteria

For example:

`<template ="26264" name="Test 127">
        <attribs>
            <add name="xInt" value="92"/>
            <add name="yInt" value="42">
                <conditions>
                    <value="1"/>
                </conditions>
            </add>
        <dependency type="absolute" valnum="9952452" count="10"/>
    </template>
    <template ="26265" name="Gamma 19">
        <attribs>
            <add name="xInt" value="12"/>
            <add name="yInt" value="109">
                <conditions>
                    <value="1"/>
                </conditions>
            </add>
        <dependency type="trans" valnum="511650" count="10"/>
        <ownership type="inherit" count="2"/>
    </template>
    <template ="26266" name="Gamma 64">
        <attribs>
            <add name="xInt" value="105"/>
            <add name="yInt" value="9">
                <conditions>
                    <value="1"/>
                </conditions>
            </add>
        <dependency type="absolute" valnum="9952452" count="10"/>
    </template>`

In the code excerpt above I'm trying to search for any template containing the code "`<dependency type="absolute" valnum="9952452" count="10"/>`" - using the Mark feature I can bookmark that one line. However I want to bookmark the entire template that has that line, so basically I want to bookmark the entire template 26264 and 26266 without getting 26265.

The purpose of that is to extract entire templates which have that relevant line in them to use for something else so if another software option can easily accomplish this I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need using a simple trick: temporarily make every section a single line.

1. Find a character not used in your file, e.g. `*`
2. Replace all newlines by `*` so your file content becomes single line
3. Replace `*`'s in `</template>*    <template` (template boundary) with newlines so your file has each template in a single line after this operation
4. Mark lines matching your criteria, e.g. `<dependency type="absolute" valnum="9952452" count="10"/>`
5. Delete unmarked lines (or copy marked lines into new file)
6. In your results, replace `*`'s back to newlines so now you have file in original format, but containing only requested templates